# How were Soviet nuclear weapons controlled?

Tags: soviet-union

Gobrachev said that the reason he allowed the Soviet Union to collapse was to prevent a civil war involving nuclear weapons.  I think Kazakhastan returned the nukes in its territory, well after the breakup of the Soviet Union. In this context, what was the control and command structure of the Soviet nuclear forces, and what effect did it have on history if any?

Comment: Some details on Ukraine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_and_Ukraine